# How can i search in a treeView1 for words/strings in items using textBox1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a new form with a treeView1 and a textBox1.

I want that when i type a word in the textBox1 if it will match the word in any of the items in any of the nodes highlight this word.

For example if i type hello in the textBox1 it will find all the places hello exist.

But if i type only h or he it should not highlight the words hello

And maybe to add Enter key for the textBox1 or a button click event to confirm when searching.

Now i'm using textBox1_TextChanged event but i'm not sure if thats a good idea.

In general i want to search for words in all Lists items in the treeView.

Now when i just type a letter/char in the textBox1 it's jumping to the treeView1 and collapse places i didn't want it to. Not working as i wanted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class DisplayResponses : Form
    {
        TreeNode[] treeNodes;
        private List<string> nodesNames = new List<string>();
        private List<TreeNode> CurrentNodeMatches = new List<TreeNode>();
        private int LastNodeIndex = 0;
        private string LastSearchText;

        public DisplayResponses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            addmore();
        }

        public void addmore()
        {
            foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
            {
                TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);

                for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
                {
                    l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisplayResponses_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
            {

                foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
                {
                    /*if (textBox1.Text == tn.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(tn.Text);
                    }*/

                    int positionOfDream = tn.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
                    if (positionOfDream != -1)
                    {
                        string name = tn.Text.Substring(positionOfDream, textBox1.Text.Length);
                        if (textBox1.Text == tn.Text)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(tn.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this part:

```
if (textBox1.Text == tn.Text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tn.Text);
}
```

It was working it was Showing the name of a node when i typed the complete name of a node.
Now in this part:

```
int positionOfDream = tn.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
if (positionOfDream != -1)
{
    string name = tn.Text.Substring(positionOfDream, textBox1.Text.Length);
    if (textBox1.Text == tn.Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tn.Text);
    }
}
```

I want that if i type the complete node name or if i type a part of node name it will Show it or any other nodes that have this part of name too.
For example if the node name is: Hello world

If i typed Hello it will show me Hello world and also other nodes names that have the word Hello inside
But if i type only H don't show me all the nodes with H in the name.

After this part will work i want to add another part that when i type in the textBox1 any string not one letter but a string for example: Hello 
So it will search in all nodes but not the names of the nodes but inside each node tree.
For example i have a node name: Hello World
If i click on the '+' near it it will collapse and show me like 70 items/child nodes.
I want to search on this 70 items/child nodes for the string i type in the textBox1.

A string/word should be from three letters and on. If i type something less then three letters don't search in the 70 items/child nodes but keep searching in the nodes names like above.

Comment: the line "string name =" is not used and will cause an error if positionOfDream > 0

Comment: Right i'm not sure yet how to use the variable name if at all. But i tried to explain in my question edited it now what i want to do. Tried to clear it as much as i can about what i want it to do.

Comment: "If i click on the '+' near it it will collapse" expand. collapse is when they disapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are code that will search all the nodes for a full match and highlight the background red:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            Call(tn); 
        }
    }

    private void Call(TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        if (treeNode.Text == textBox1.Text)
        {
            treeNode.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            treeNode.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            Call(tn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working good. And if i want to highlight keywords of nodes names and also inside a node tree ? For example if i type hello it will color in Red all the places the word hello exist including inside the nodes not only in the nodes names.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

"A string/word should be from three letters and on."
To get it to run only when 3 letters or more have been typed change

```
if (textBox1.Text != "")
```

to

```
if (textBox1.TextLength >= 3)
{
   //search child items only
}
else
{
   //search items only
}
```